# How to loop this code for 50 times and append the output json it generates and store it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, curl

this code generates a random 50 json strings and posts through curl.      Due to the limitations cant post after 33676. Is there a way to load json directly in grpcurl or curl.  Else how to loop this code 50 times and append the output json to a single file.

If we use subprocess in python it will open,read the json and cmd char count exceeds upto 33676

if we send json file more than 33676 chars it responds with content too long in cmd and command tooo long in shell

```
import faker
import json
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
import json
import os
#subprocess.call([""])
from pprint import pprint

ids= ('5cda','6cda')

fake = Faker('en_US')

for ind in ids:
    cont = []
    #Overall dictionary with first and user_ids
    dct = {}
    for idx in range(50):

        sms =  {
            "id":"AB-asfgw",
            "body": fake.text(),
            "mime": fake.ean(),
            "hashed": fake.ean(),
            "pid": fake.ean(),
            "user_id": ind,
            "text": fake.sentence()
        }
        cont.append(sms)

    dct['messages'] = cont
    dct['user_id'] = ind
    #print(dct)
    f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
    with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
        #Save the dictionary
        json.dump(dct, fp, indent=4)
        print('saved {}'.format(f_name))    


auth = "authorization: token 1234
file = "5cda.json"
fd=open("5cda.json")
json_content = fd.read()
fd.close()


subprocess.run(["curl", "-plaintext","-H", auth,"-d",json_content,"-format","json","100.10.10.10:1000","service/methodname"])



auth1 = "authorization: token 12345"
file1 = "6cda.json"
fd1=open("6cda.json")
json_content1 = fd1.read()
fd1.close()

subprocess.run(["curl", "-plaintext","-H", auth1,"-d",json_content1,"-format","json",""100.10.10.10:1000","service/methodname"])
```

Comment: Your question is still a bit vague. What "limitations" are you seeing after "33676"? I don't understand either.

Comment: If we use subprocess in python it will open,read the json and cmd char count exceeds upto 33676 and if we send json file more than 33676 chars it responds with content too long in cmd and command tooo long in shell.

Comment: That means that the curl request is too long, not the JSON. Why not load it into a file and send that instead? You won't have a length limit that way.

Comment: need it in grpcurl . Couldn't  find how to load a file in grpcurl.   -d sends string , @ opens stdin both didnt work. -import-value is asking   need proto files. configured protos but couldn't figure out

Comment: Then loop over the different files you store in, loop over the 50 json entries and send them one at a time.

Comment: yes thats my question. currently i am using  another script to loop this script 50 times but i couldn't save the all the json data that has been generated cz i am looping the python script and only the last recent one will be saved. I need help in appending these random json data that has been generated